# How can I change table height?

Tags: html, css, web

CSS:

```
td, table { 
border: 
1px solid black 
}

.space {
padding:0px;
border-spacing:1px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table style="width:800px" class="space">
    <tr>
        <td><p>A</p></td>
        <td><p>B</p></td>
        <td><p>C</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>D</p></td>
        <td><p>E</p></td>
        <td><p>F</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>G</p></td>
        <td><p>H</p></td>
        <td><p>I</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>J</p></td>
        <td><p>K</p></td>
        <td><p>L</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I can't make the table height smaller. I want the rows to be about half as small.

Suggestions?

(This is the code to the original table, without any alteration trying to make it lower in height as I want it)

Answer (score 3):

The p tag has a margin. So that causes the height issue. Add the following code to your css file to get rid of that margin:

```
p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: God I love this website, fixed my problem instantly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css:

```
.p{
     height: 0.7em;
 }
```

As @Wezelkrozum says, p has a default height.
Alternatively, you could try using div & br instead of p